# How to prove that every nonabelian group of odd order is not simple?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, simple-groups

How to prove or disprove that every nonabelian group of odd order is not simple? I have no ideas concerning that.

Comment: The proof of this result takes over 250 pages, so it is not reasonable to expect somebody to reproduce it here!

Comment: @ Derek Holt: Can you give a reference?

Comment: As others have said already, it's the Feit-Thompson Theorem, Feit, Walter; Thompson, John G. (1963), "Solvability of groups of odd order", Pacific Journal of Mathematics 13: 775–1029.

Comment: @ Derek Holt: I don't have in mind the proof of Feiit-Thomson theorem. I have in mind the answer to my question.

Comment: Link to online copy at project euclid [here](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1103053941).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.** See [Feit-Thompson Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feit%E2%80%93Thompson_theorem) and show that it is equivalent to the statement that finite nonabelian simple groups have even order.

Comment: @ iHubble: Could you explain your suggestion in detail? This is not a homework.

Comment: If you can show that, then it will imply by the contrapositive that every nonabelian group of odd order cannot be simple.

Comment: @ iHubble: Unfortunately, I can't show that, can you? Thank you anyway.

Comment: See [here](http://math.berkeley.edu/~dpenneys/math252/cueto_15_5.pdf).

Comment: What iHubble is getting at, maybe a little obliquely, is that this is a very hard and famous theorem.

Comment: @ iHubble: Sorry, but the link is not currently (on 27.08.14) working. In view of that I have to refuse my acception.

Answer (score 0):

The Feit-Thompson theorem states that every finite group of odd order is solvable. So any group of odd order will have a proper commutator subgroup, which is normal, essentially by the defintion of being solvable $( G \vartriangleright [G,G] \vartriangleright ... \vartriangleright 1).$ Since the group is not abelian, the commutator subgroup $[G,G]$ not the trivial group. That means that $[G,G]$ is a proper nontrivial normal subgroup, so $G$ is not simple.

Comment: @ Disciple of Barney : Can you kindly elaborate your answer?

Comment: @user64494 Is that better?

Comment: @ Disciple of Barney : Yes, that is better as you added some details. Sorry, but I still don't understand "Since the group is not abelian, the commutator subgroup $[G,G] $ not the trivial group ".

Comment: @user64494 The commutator subgroup is the group of elements generated by $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$, for all $a,b \in G$, and note that $a,b$ commute if, and only if, $aba^{-1}b^{-1}=1$. If we have a non abelian group, that means there is a pair $a,b$ that does not commute, so $aba^{-1}b^{-1}\neq 1$, hence the commutator subgroup of a nonabelian group contains a non identity element, so is not the trivial group.